# Django Migration Error without DateTime field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I tried to insert a new field in my model and I got a DateTime Migration error, So I deleted those two fields and am trying to run "migrate" function which is not working , Make migration still work though.

```
D:\trydjango\src>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

D:\trydjango\src>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, auth, sessions, admin, posts
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying posts.0009_auto_20170213_1754...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py
", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92
, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_ini
tial)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 12
1, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_
initial)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 19
8, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 1
23, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, projec
t_state)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py"
, line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", lin
e 221, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", lin
e 103, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 2
10, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1461, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1440, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1296, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1399, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 93, in pa
rse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

D:\trydjango\src>
```

Below is my Models.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Invoice(models.Model):
active = models.BooleanField()
bu_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
invoice_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
sow_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
probability = models.IntegerField()
sow_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
sow_start_date = models.DateField()
sow_end_date = models.DateField()
project_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
project_manager = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
po_number = models.IntegerField()
sow_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
current_month = models.CharField(max_length=20)
current_year = models.CharField(max_length=5)
month_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
q1_value = models.IntegerField()
q2_value = models.IntegerField()
q3_value = models.IntegerField()
q4_value = models.IntegerField()
total_value_ofyear = models.IntegerField()
probability_month_value = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.invoice_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("invoice:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

There are no new fields , everything is back as it was but not i am getting this error.

Comment: Please post *text* as text, images are harder to read and less accessible.

Comment: @Sayse Sure.. Sorry

Comment: Did you also delete the migration file that you created? when you added the two new fields? (Which I'm guessing was `posts.0009`)

Comment: @Sayse Yeah I did!!